# A Hilbert ring in integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Is the ring $R=\left\{ \frac{a}{2b+1} : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$ a Hilbert ring?

This is the localization of $\mathbb Z$ at the prime ideal $(2)$ each prime ideal of which corresponds to any prime ideal of $\mathbb Z$ having void intersection with the set of odd integers . So, the only prime ideal is $\left\{ \frac{2a}{2b+1} \right\}$... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not: $(0)$ is not the intersection of the maximal ideals containing it.